# .NET form validation library for WinForms, MVC4, and a WCF API

Tags: .net, winforms, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have a project where we implement a range of complex legal forms for use with performing electronic transactions with a statutory authority.

Our product is accessible as a desktop WinForms app, via an MVC4 website, and also via a REST API.

Currently we have custom validation rules built into user events for WinForms and much the same with jQuery-based validation in MVC4.

I'm looking at having to re-code the validation all over again in order to provide request validation for a REST API.

Is there a library or package I can use to create a single DLL that will validate submitted data no matter the input source? It'd be great to have all the form validation logic maintained in one place and then deployed as needed. We don't just validate form fields; we have to validate against the backend database also. The spec from the statutory authority runs to thousands of pages.

Comment: your problem here is that you are asking about Server Side Validation replacing Client Side Validation.  There isn't going to be a universal client validation library.

Comment: MVC4 has server-side validation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710702/ASP-NET-MVC-Server-Side-Validation but I don't think DataAnnotations is going to be complex enough for our purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kind of understand what you need :

Below is our approach which can come handy in your library design:
Assuming that your project follows traditional layered architecture you can put your validation in your [Domain Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)

What Library to use?
We use [Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) so you can add a reference to your projects by simply installing it in your application:

```
Install-Package FluentValidation.MVC5
```

But How to use it?

Define an abstract BaseValidator class *similar* to below implmentation and adapt it to your need:

```
public abstract class BaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : class
{
    public bool IsValid(T entity)
    {
        return Validate(entity).IsValid;
    }

    private bool IsValid(T entity, out IList<ValidationFailure> errors)
    {
        var result = Validate(entity);
        errors = result.Errors;

        return Validate(entity).IsValid;
    }

    public bool IsValidOrException(T entity)
    {
        IList<ValidationFailure> errors;

        if (!IsValid(entity, out errors))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Entity of type {0} is not valid:", typeof(T).Name));

            var failures = new List<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure>(errors.Count);

            foreach (var errorMessage in errors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(errorMessage.ErrorMessage);

                FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure failure = new FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure(errorMessage.PropertyName, errorMessage.ErrorMessage);

                failures.Add(failure);
            }

            throw new ValidationException(failures);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public new ValidateResult Validate(T entity)
    {
        ValidationResult validationResult = base.Validate(entity);
        IList<ValidationFailure> failures = new List<ValidationFailure>();

        for (var i = 0; i < validationResult.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            var error = validationResult.Errors[i];
            failures.Add(new ValidationFailure(error.ErrorMessage, error.PropertyName));
        }

        ValidateResult result = new ValidateResult(validationResult.IsValid, failures);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now what?

For every entity which needs validation define its own validator just like the following for currency(As an example) validation:

```
    internal class CurrencyValidator : BaseValidator<Currency>
{
    public CurrencyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.IsoThreeLetter).Length(3, 3).WithMessage("Currency requires IsoCode of 3 letters");
        RuleFor(x => x.Symbol).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Currency requires a symbol");
        RuleFor(x => x.HtmlSymbol).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Currency requires a html symbol");
    }
}
```

How to validate now?
Simple Just like follows:

```
    public void AddCurrency(Currency currency)
    {
        if (new CurrencyValidator().IsValidOrException(currency))
        {
            _dto.Currencies.Add(currency);
        }
    }
```

Above approach is quite generic and reusable and could be kept in sepereate DLL as a part of your domain layer.